# How to connect to Multiple profile in WebSphere by executing the wsadmin script in command prompt for deploment through Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, websphere-7

I can able to connect to only one profile at a time through jenkins(websphere deployer plugin) by executing the below command

```
(was_home/bin)/> sh wsadmin.sh -profileName AppSrv07 -host  xxxx  -port 8887 -username yyy -password zzz -profileName AppSrv09 -host xxxx -port 8886 -username uuuu -password gggg.
```

Even when I try to connect to 2 profiles, connection was made to only one profile.

Please help me how to connect to mutliple profile using wsadimin script so that connection to different profile which is used by Jenkins jobs for deployment should be success.

As of now I can able to connect to only one profile.

Comment: If you want to connect concurrently to many profiles, then it is not possible. `wsadmin` can be connected to one profile at a time. However you can close one wsadmin session and connect to different profile.

Comment: Hi Braian, Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Other than executing "wsadmin" script,  is there any other way to connect to mutiple profile at a time. Please help me.

Comment: **can anyone please help on this requirement**

Comment: I've already answered that - there is NO WAY single wsadmin session be connected at the same time to multiple profiles.

Comment: Hi Gas thanks for info, I agree that it is not possible to connect to 2 profiles in the same time if we use "wsadmin". 

But i'm still wondering if there is any another way(**other than wsadmin**) to connect 2 or more profiles at the same time to do the deployment in Jenkins.

Comment: I don't know Jenkins well enough, but cant you just deploy to one profile and then to the second, not at the same time? If you really have to connect to 2 profiles, you could use [Job manager](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/cagt_jobmanager.html?lang=en), register 2 profiles there and schedule jobs to be executed, but the setup is quite complex.

Comment: Hi, Can i write the perl script to copy the WAR file into the physical location of the WebSphere by stopping the profile - copy the WAR file - start the profile. **Will this work?**

Comment: You dont have to stop the profile. You can use feature called monitored directory and just copy your ear/war file there. It will work. See for more info and how to set it up here - [Installing enterprise application files by adding them to a monitored directory](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/trun_app_install_dragdrop.html?lang=en)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done when I had more than one profile and it worked. 
In the script being run, do `exefile('<profile>')` -
this will make the profile available to the script. Hope it helps.

Comment: typo - *being run